# The preg_match function doesn't accept the symbol "/"

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
  $URI = "controller/method/parms";
  $pattern = "a-z0-9_-/";
  echo preg_match("/^[". $pattern ."]+$/i", $URI);
```

Because of this `/` symbol, the operation fails and appears this error:
`Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']'`. but if I remove that symbol, everything will work correctly.

Comment: Escape slash `$pattern = "a-z0-9_\/-";`

Comment: @splash58: Thank you, you are right. The problem was in the order of the symbol, it was not supposed to put the symbol at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Really, I don't see any reason to vote me down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the slash and move the dash at the end of the character class:

```
$pattern = "a-z0-9_\/-";
preg_match("/^[". $pattern ."]+$/i", $URI);
```

Note: preg_quote doesn't work in this case because it escapes the dash, I don't know why.

You could also use another delimiter:

```
$pattern = "a-z0-9_/-";
preg_match("~^[". $pattern ."]+$~i", $URI);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message still appears, in both cases.

Comment: @LionKing: Sorry, I missed the second parameter :)

Comment: If you `preg_quote()` the `$pattern` that contains `\w` the `\w` will get escaped and won't match.

Comment: @nickb: True, I remove it.

Comment: Thanks, the error message disappeared, but always the function returns 0, and that mean it has failed.

Comment: @LionKing:Preg_quote escape the dash, even in the range `a-z`, that's crazy. See my edit for an alternative.

Comment: @Toto: `preg_quote` is designed to escape literal strings, not a character class content. It escapes regex special characters `. \\ ? + * ( ) { [ | ^ $` but in addition it escapes also characters that are used in special sequences: `=` => `(?=...)`, `]` => `[...]`, `}` => `{m,n}`, `-` => `(?-i)`, `>` => `(?>...)`, `:` => `(?:...)`, etc. Note that strangely it doesn't escape the `#` that is used in comment groups: `(?#...)`

Comment: @LionKing: Anyway, since the edited version answers the question, you should accept it.